# drawRect Circle inside of circle used to show progress

Tags: iphone, ios, geometry, progress, drawrect

I'm trying to show progress by having a circle fill up with another circle inside of it. Can someone help me achieve this? I may be going about this the wrong way.
Here is my code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 400, 500, 500);
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 500, 500) cornerRadius:50.0] addClip];


    CGContextRef contextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(contextRef, 2.0);
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(contextRef, 111/255.0f, 116/255.0f, 128/255.0f, 1.0);
    CGRect circlePoint = (CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(contextRef, circlePoint);

    CGContextBeginPath(contextRef);

    float c = 20; //Number that should cause the green progress to increase and decrease
    CGContextAddArc(contextRef, 250, 250, 250, 0, M_PI, 0);
    CGContextClosePath(contextRef); // could be omitted
    UIColor *color = [UIColor greenColor];
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(contextRef, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillPath(contextRef);
}
```

And here is a screenshot of how it looks right now. I basically want to be able to control the progress of the green inside using my `float c;` variable.

I've tried playing around with `CGContextAddArc`, but I can't get grow to the size of the circle as "c" increases and same when I decrease the value of "c"

[image: c]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use your c to say from where to where

```
// draw the pie part
CGContextMoveToPoint(_viewContext, centerX, centerY);
CGContextAddArc(_viewContext, centerX, centerY, pieRadius, radians(startDegrees), radians(endDegrees), 0);
CGContextClosePath(_viewContext);
CGContextFillPath(_viewContext);
```

- startDegrees = 0
- endDegress = c
- _viewContext = contextRef
- centerX/CenterY = center of bounds
- PieRadius = radius you want :D in pixels IIRC

to convert deg to rad

```
#define pi 3.14159265
double radians(double percentage)
{
    return (percentage/100)*360 * (pi/180);
}
```

Comment: It's working! Do you know why the progress is not just going straight up though? It goes up from the side randomly. Thanks for the help! Here are some screenshots: 25%: http://d.pr/i/CCv6 50%: http://d.pr/i/caOU 75%: http://d.pr/i/GbhF

Comment: ah now I see what you want. you want to have it fill the circle from bottom to top.. kinda like a 'glas' -- this isn't random. it is starting at RAD=0. If you want to fill it up from the bottom just draw it all as a rectangle. and clip it to the shape of a circle